# How do I match regular expressions with strings?

Tags: java, regex

in Java, what regular-expression will match the following string (please note that the `|` is part of the string)?

```
|---0-1-2-5-3-||-3-----------|---------1-0-|-0-----------|
```

Comment: What's the pattern you want to match? If you need exact match with the string above, simple use str.equals("|---0-1-2-5-3-||....")

Comment: wat have u tried?and is the regex to match this specific string or to match a pattern?for the first case a regex is not needed.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are the rules for matching/not matching a string? For example, `.*` would match the string, but you're most likely looking for something more restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above by Eyal Schneider and Naveed S:

if you need to match that exact string, use

```
str.equals("|---0-1-2-5-3-||-3-----------|---------1-0-|-0-----------|")
```

if you need to match a certain pattern within the string, use RegEx.

A [Tutorial on Java Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

A tester where you can [test your Regular Expressions](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: There's a more simpler expression that will match this line: `.*` The OP never said he wanted to match ONLY the example string ;)

Comment: True, that's why I suggested Regex Tutorial and the tester as well.
Thanks for the edit assylias.